# How can I make a join between two tables keeping specific records from each table according to a condition

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables t1, t2 I want for example to get all the results from t1 except when itemType = '01' in which case I want to keep the correspondent itemType='01' record from t2, and this is the only record I want from t2.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and include the following: Your DBMS, Table Structure / Sample Data, Your attempt (if any - this is not a code writing service), and expected output based on sample data. Thanks

Comment: Sample data, please.

Comment: Are the two tables based on an inner join or an outer join?

Answer (score 0):

Try a case statement for the field
This way ONLY that field is selected based on the condition you described

Assuming in the example below an inner join, however we could changes this to an outer join and add a little logic for handling nulls.

Depending on the relationship in the data, you may need to group by to get to the correct level of information/avoid duplicates.  Still the example should help

For example,

```
select t1.field1, t1.field2, etc, 

case 
when t1.itemType = '01' then t2.itemType 
else t1.itemType 
end 

from
(
  (select * from tableA) as T1
    inner join
  (select * from tableB) as T2
     On T1.key1 = T2.key1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want `UNION ALL` and not a `JOIN`:

```
select * from t1
where itemtype <> '01'
union all
select * from t2
where itemtype = '01'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a `left join` with filtering parses into the description you have given:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1 join
     t2
     on t2.? = t1.? and  -- however you define corresponding
        t2.itemType = '01'
where t1.itemType <> '01';
```